# Excel ¿cómo hacer una plantilla de presupuesto de más de una página?

Tags: excel

Tengo que hacer una plantilla de presupuestos en Excel para la empresa donde trabajo y la condición es que a veces el presupuesto tendrá una hoja, dos o tres, y necesito que **en cada hoja aparezca el encabezado** (concepto | cantidad | precio) de forma automática, y además que **las celdas con el IVA y el total aparezcan solo en la última hoja al final**.

¿Se puede hacer? ¿Cómo?

¡Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Que has intentado?, Tu pregunta lleva dos votos de cinco para terminar cerrada, por favor mejora la

Comment: Solucionada y finalizada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo he hecho un ejemplo sencillo. Me he inventado artículos y he hecho una lista larga. Si miro el documento en Vista PReliminar, la segunda página, de primeras, no tiene el encabezado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi hoja Excel es así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que vamos a hacer es en la cinta de opciones superior, en la pestaña DISPOSICIÓN DE PÁGINA, clic en IMPRIMIR TÍTULOS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cuadro de diálogo que verás, en el campo REPETIR FILAS EN EXTREMO SUPERIOR, tienes que poner las filas que quieres que se repitan (en mi caso la 4):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora al imprimirlo o pasarlo a PDF, te repetirá esas filas como encabezado :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes personalizar más cosas en esa misma sección (numerar páginas, márgenes, etc.)

Más info:

> [Imprimir las filas con los encabezados de columna en la parte
>   superior de todas las
>   páginas](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/imprimir-las-filas-con-los-encabezados-de-columna-en-la-parte-superior-de-todas-las-p%C3%A1ginas-d3550133-f6a1-4c72-ad70-5309a2e8fe8c)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ¡Me has solucionado el problema! Había olvidado la opción de Disposición de página > impimir títulos, además me has dado la idea de escribirlo todo hasta abajo y ya se divide al imprimir, porque yo estaba intentando hacer la plantilla de la factura como un diseño de la página entera.